# what encoding is cmd (xp) in?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

What encoding does cmd of win xp use ?

Let's say I'm trying to get some ascii box characters which show fine in cmd, in some text editor ? What enc. would I need to put it in ? Since it comes out as garbage.

---

```
write(*,*) char(218),char(196),char(196),char(191)
write(*,*) char(179),'22'      ,char(179)
write(*,*) char(179),'22'      ,char(179)
write(*,*) char(192),char(196),char(196),char(217)
end
```

Comment: Can you provide more details please? Exactly what input do you have and what output are you expecting?

Comment: I?m using a sample program (part of a much larger one) to draw box characters to a file. When viewed in cmd it looks fine (ascii box lines). But when opened with let's say vim, it looks like garbage. So I assumed it was a matter of encoding/codepage ...

Comment: Generally, the output of the above looks like a box around numbers 22 in two rows.

Comment: You might be better off if this was on Stack Overflow as it's beginning to sound like a programming question. If it is it'll get migrated so all you have to do is create an account and link it to your Super User one.

Comment: There is a similar one out there as well (under some different assumptions), not many answers, none useful ... in any case, I'll let it stay here ... maybe someone will know. This is not a programming issue, I can draw box chars in cmd by typing them. This is a codepage issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive the actual codepage use this command:

```
mode con cp
```

Comment: (btw, if you wish look for my question on SO as well regarding vim/vertsplit and i'll accept it there too). been too long since i've done anything but trivialities in cmd, and it's starting to show.
so, a big thanks  for this !

Comment: `chcp` works too.

Answer (score -1):

You can run `chcp` itself without arguments to know the active code page. AND `graftabl.com` will work on 32 bit systems.